# How to modify terminator config to first ssh to a remote server and then switch to a specific directory?

Tags: terminator

I have modified my `~/.config/terminator/config` to automatically ssh me to a remote server `foobar` by using line

```
custom_command = ssh foobar
```

but I don't know how to change to a specific directory afterwards

```
custom_command = ssh foobar; cd baz/quux
```

does not work.

Comment: Try `custom_command = ssh foobar && cd baz/quux` and report back. If that doesn't work this may need to be configured server-side.

Comment: @I_GNU_it_all_along, no good

Comment: What about `custom_command = ssh -t foobar "cd baz/quux ; bash"`?

Comment: @I_GNU_it_all_along, make it into a full fledged answer and I'll change the accepted answer to you.

Comment: Nah, it's cool, I'll let Brian have his rep ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer was introduced in a comment by [user I_GNU_it_all_along](https://superuser.com/users/639476/i-gnu-it-all-along):

```
custom_command = ssh -t foobar "cd baz/quux ; bash"
```

Answer (score 1):

What about dropping the `;` from your `custom_command`? As in:

`custom_command = ssh foobar cd baz/quux`

This should just execute the command once login is accepted, as per [ssh documentation](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/ssh1.html).

For a more permanent solution, you could always modify the `.bash_profile` (or similar) on the server to always change directories on login.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky - Give us reviewers an ultimatum isn't constructive.

Comment: Rejecting an edit that corrects an obviously incorrect answer is not constructive either, :wink: